# Entity Framework Core - Migration HasData method not setting enum value on statement

Tags: c#, .net-core, enums, entity-framework-core, migration

I was trying to seed data in a migration using the SeedData method, and one of the fields of this model was an Enum that can have several values. The issue is that when I generate the migration, that specific field is never populated in the migration. It always relays on default value even when I'm trying to set it to something different. I also tried editing one of the already seeded objects included in a previous migration and it's also not generating an UpdateData migration. I manually tested adding myself the UpdateData statement but I wanted to know if we're doing something wrong with SeedData and Enum values.

SourceType.cs

```
public enum SourceType {
  Email,
  Sms,
  Phone
}
```

Source.cs

```
public class Source {
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}

  public SourceType Type {get;set;}
}
```

HasData use

```
...

modelBuilder.Entity<Source>().HasData(
  new Source{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Email Source",
    Type = SourceType.Email
  })

...
```

BunchOfDateNumbers_Migration.cs Up method

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
  table: "Source",
  columns: new[]{"Id", "Name"},
  values: new[] {1, "Email Source"})
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do we have to specify enum values manually?

EDIT:

We also set this value by default:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Source>(
    entity =>
    {
      entity.Property(e => e.SourceType).HasDefaultValueSql("1");
    });
```

Comment: What is the primary key (don't see it in the example)? It is required for data seeding

Comment: @IvanStoev This is a partial class, I did hide a lot of properties and forgot to add PK. Give me a sec and I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks, let me see if I can duplicate it... Just in case, the EF Core version you are using is?

Comment: Does not reproduce (EFC 6.0) - I'm getting `migrationBuilder.InsertData(
    table: "Source",
    columns: new[] { "Id", "Name", "Type" },
    values: new object[] { 1, "Email Source", 0 });` May be something else  is missing (for instance `HasDefaultValue`)?

Comment: Yes, we have a default value. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: And our EFCore version is 7.0.0-preview.6.22329.4

Answer (score 1):

EF Core uses the CLR default to determine if the SQL DEFAULT should be used. Since SourceType.Email is the CLR default (0) it doesn't send an INSERT value so the DEFAULT constraint can be used. There are several ways to "fix" this.

First, you could just start your enum at 1:

```cs
enum SourceType {
  Email = 1,
  Sms,
  Phone
}
```

Or second, you could add a better enum value for the default.

```cs
enum SourceType {
  Unknown, // "None" or "Default" are also good names
  Email,
  Sms,
  Phone
}
```

Or third, you can make the property nullable so that `null` becomes the default CLR value instead of 0.

```cs
class Source {

  // Nullable to allow both using the DEFAULT and inserting SourceType.Email
  public SourceType? Type {get;set;}

}
```